# Does it require to install all necessary software for slave in jenkins

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, testng, jenkins

I have built automation script and everything working perfectly. Now client want to run same script from his location.

I am thinking to set his computer as slave in jenkins , but does it require to install selenium and all other software in client computer?

And what will be solution if client do not want to install anything and still want to run script from his computer. I know I can export project as executable JARs but that I am not preferring for some reasons.

Comment: Install your jenkin in any of web server and configure your job then simply you can share url of the job .So your client can execute the scripts from his end with out any installation

Comment: Web server means godady, hostgator something? And my project is on local machine then will also have to upload it on web server?

Comment: Yes.you should upload to  your server.